# Activeadmin - HTML in textarea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've recently started using the Activeadmin gem for my Ruby on Rails blog. In my post model I have a `title:string` and `body:text`. How can I use HTML and css in my active admin textarea so I can divide my text into paragraphs and add styles to my body text?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you would need WYSIWYG text editors gem like CKEdtior.

Comment: If you are creating a blog, consider Refinery CMS which is built on Rails as a Rails engine. https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself. The view accepted HTML and CSS if I just added `.html_safe`. For example `<%= @post.body.html_safe %>`. Easiest solution for now.

Comment: Even thought this is the answer you accepted, it sounds like this is a partial answer.  SO is about long-term community value; I propose this answer be un-marked, if a mod can do, since it does not answer the question.

Comment: This doesn't even explain how to create a text area in the ActiveAdmin form! Never mind, had to restart the server after changing the column type because ActiveAdmin caches the model fields, even in development.